# how to write if else statement with passed data in dart (flutter app)

Tags: dart, flutter

I am trying to write an if/else statement in dart on my flutter app. I am trying to see if the passed id is equal to 3 to return a whole page of code, and else would be a different page. for example...

```
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final TextEditingController controller = new TextEditingController();
    String result = "";
    If (${widget.id} = 3){ 
        return Scaffold(
           all of scaffold 1)
       }; else {
          return Scaffold(
            all of scaffold 2)
       };
```

Do i need to set `${widget.id}` to a variable to call into the if statement? And where would i set it in the .dart page, in `void initstate(){}`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The syntax would be:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  final TextEditingController controller = new TextEditingController();
  String result = "";
  if (widget.id == 3) {
    return Scaffold(/* version 1*/);
  } else {
    return Scaffold(/* version 2*/);
  }
}
```

`id` would be set in the constructor of the `StatefulWidget` - and should be final.

Answer (score 2):

You can also do it like this

Using a ternary operator

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
 final TextEditingController controller = new TextEditingController();
 String result = "";
 return widget.id == 3 ? Scaffold(/*version 1*/) : Scaffold(/*version 2*/);
}
```